# Remove duplicate claims from ClaimsPrincipal

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

Assuming I have the following setup:

Roles: `[Role1, Role2]`
RoleClaims: `[{Role1, ClaimType1, ClaimValue1}, {Role2, ClaimType1, ClaimValue1}]`

Basically there are two roles, and both roles has role claim `ClaimType1 = ClaimValue1`

Then I have a user who is assigned to both roles. If I look at the claims identity of this user I will see

```
[
    ClaimType1 = ClaimValue1
    ClaimType1 = ClaimValue1
]
```

I think behind the scene asp.net identity just calls `SignInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync` which iterates thru all roles and add all the claims returned from `RoleManager.GetClaimsAsync`.

Whats the easiest way to ignore duplicated claims(the ones that have the same type + value) while the user principal is being generated or right after it has been generated?